# I18next load translation with locally with bundled translation files

Tags: i18next, react-i18next, i18next-http-backend

Is there a way for me to load translations from a translation json files bundled with my js files?

I only have a few languages to cover, and due to restrictions setting up a backend endpoint is not possible.

I am aware of the addResourceBundle function, but have been unsuccessful in doing so.

I have translation file **english.json**, **spanish.json**

```
i18next.init();
i18next.addResourceBundle('en', 'translation', english.json);
i18next.addResourceBundle('es', 'translation', spanish.json);
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

In order to bundle your translation files with the js code, you need to add them to the dependency tree of your app.

I guess that you are using webpack, you need to define a loader for json imports ([json-loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/json-loader/)).

```js
i18next.init({
  resources: {
    'en-US': {translation: require('./en-us/translation.json')},
    // ---------^ namespace
    'nl-NL': {translation: require('./nl-nl/translation.json')},
  },
  fallbackLng: 'en-US',
  ns: ['translation'],
  defaultNS: 'translation',
});
```

Comment: Hi, it works to load the resource, but now the backend api wouldn't work?

`i18next.init(
resources:{},
backend:{
loadpath: someEndPoint/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json
}}`

When selecting a language not available with the bundle, it should've called to the endpoint to retrieve the translations, but now no request is being sent and the UI is suspended.

Comment: Oops, sorry.
Totally missed 
`partialBundledLanguages: "true",`
It's working now! 
It's good to know as it opens up possibility for expansion

Comment: I am using the key 'nl-NL' for loading resource but it's not working. maybe the `'` not working for key